# How can I insert the data inside a new object in for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this possible? When I try to do this the output is not what I expected. Heres is

```
var data = 10,
    test = new Array;

for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {
  test = {
       i : {
        'Title' : 'Title-Data',
        'optionFilter' : {
          'AssetClass' : 'AssetClass-Data',
          'Region' : 'Region-Data',
          'Style' : 'Style-Data',
          'TypeofClient' : 'TypeofClient-Data'
        }
      },
  }
};

console.log( test );
```

Thanks, :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `test` is an array, just use the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {
  test.push({
        'Title' : 'Title-Data',
        'optionFilter' : {
          'AssetClass' : 'AssetClass-Data',
          'Region' : 'Region-Data',
          'Style' : 'Style-Data',
          'TypeofClient' : 'TypeofClient-Data'
        }
      });
}
```

If you wanted to achieve something similar with an object, it would look a bit like this:

```
var data = 10,
    test = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {
  test[i] = {
        'Title' : 'Title-Data',
        'optionFilter' : {
          'AssetClass' : 'AssetClass-Data',
          'Region' : 'Region-Data',
          'Style' : 'Style-Data',
          'TypeofClient' : 'TypeofClient-Data'
        }
      };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

better to use `new Array()` or just `vat test = []`; to declare an array then use `push` method to populate an array

```
    var data = 10,
        test = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < data; i++) {
      test.push({           
            'Title' : 'Title-Data',
            'optionFilter' : {
                 'AssetClass' : 'AssetClass-Data',
                 'Region' : 'Region-Data',
                 'Style' : 'Style-Data',
                 'TypeofClient' : 'TypeofClient-Data' 
             }          
          });
   }
```

Comment: `new Array` (without parentheses) is the same as `new Array()`, at least according to 11.2.2 of the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).